# How can I set a header/Content-length in SoapClient?

Tags: header, soap-client, content-length

Is there any way I can set Content-length in the header when sending request with SoapClient?

I guess it should be possible to do that in `SoapHeader` function. But it is not clear to me how to input content-length in there. There is just mentioned setting of namespace in the documentation. But I dont need to change namespace or anything like that (it is already set in the wsdl file)..

Thanks for any useful answer.